# $L_\infty$ norm minimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I write supplemental explanation to render my aim of optimization.

First Consider **discrete time** linear system below:

\begin{equation} G(z)=\frac{1-e^{-0.3T}}{z^{100}(z-e^{-0.3T})} \end{equation}

where $z = e^{j\omega}$ and $\omega$ is **frequency**, $\omega \in [-\pi,\pi)$, and $T$ is sampling period, assume that $T = 1$. It's obvious that the absolute value of $z$  is equal to $1$ for all $\omega$ between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

When one is talking about maximum absolute value of $G(z)$, in fact he/she consider below function :

\begin{equation} \max_{\omega} |G(e^{j\omega})|=|\frac{1-e^{-0.3T}}{e^{j\omega}-e^{-0.3T}}|  . \end{equation}

note that $|z^{100}| = |z|^{100} = 1.$

On the other hand consider another discrete time linear system :

\begin{equation} C(z) = \frac{(x+\frac{T}{2}y)z+(\frac{T}{2}y-x)}{z-1} \end{equation}

Consider these two linear system connected serially.Then the closed loop system transfer function (with unity feedback)  is:

\begin{equation} f(x,y,z) = \frac{G(z)C(z)}{1+G(z)C(z)}\end{equation}

or

\begin{equation} f(x,y,e^{j\omega}) = \frac{G(e^{j\omega})C(e^{j\omega})}{1+G(e^{j\omega})C(e^{j\omega})}\end{equation}

**My aim** is to minimize the maximum absolute value of $f$ (respect to $\omega$) over $x $ and $ y$ as mathematically described bellow:

\begin{equation} \min_{x, y} \max_{z \; or \; \omega} |f(x,y,z)|\end{equation}

This is equal to minimizing the $L_\infty$ norm of $f$ (respect to $\omega$) over $x$ and $y$ (right?) In fact:

\begin{equation}\min_{x, y} \max_{\omega} |f(x,y,\omega)| \equiv  \min_{x, y} ||f(x,y,\omega)||_{\infty , \;\omega}\end{equation}

How can I do the optimization with Mathematica?

---

I try the code below for defining the function and maximizing $f$ respect to $z$:

```
T = 0.01
z = Exp[I w]
f = (((x + (T/2) y) z + ((T/2) y - x)) (1 - Exp[-0.3 T]))/(
      (z^100) (z - Exp[-0.3 T]) (z - 1) + ((x + (T/2) y) z + ((T/2) y - x)) (1 - Exp[-0.3 T]))
maxp = First[ NMaximize[{f[x, y, w], 0 <= w <= 10}, w, Method -> DifferentialEvolution]]
```

But when I run code, the following error appears:

> ```
> NMaximize::nnum: The function value 
> -((0.0029955 (-x + (0.89724 + 0.441543 I) (x + 0.005 y) + 0.005 y))/((0.120832 -0.165872 I)
>  + 0.0029955 ( -x + (0.89724 + <<20>> I) (<<1>>)+0.005 y)))[x,y,0.457318] 
> is not a number at {w} = {0.457318}. >>
> ```

I try different intervals for $w$ but nothing changed.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: This can be done as a bilevel optimization. See [this MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Aug/msg00370.html) or [this Matlab Usenet group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/qfxSqXEhHa4) or the "fewnomial" example [here](http://www.omicsonline.com/open-access/2090-4908/2090-4908-1-103.pdf)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. But I have problem with doing that. I added more details in question.

Comment: That's very confused code. First, you might want f[x_,y_,z_]:=... Then there is the bit about defining z=Exp[I*w] and later invoking f[x,y,w]. Very confusing as to what specifically you want for that third argument. Finally there is absolutely no indication of what you do to minimize over `{x,y}` , and that is precisely the sort of thing covered at the links I posted.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I'm new with mathematica. Sorry for these silly mistakes. I don't know what do you mean by doing " [x_,p_Real,n_]". Could you explain more?

Comment: A pattern such as _Real in e.g `f[x_,p_Real,n_]` means the function `f[]` will not evaluate UNLESS that argument is an explicit real number, e.g. f[x,5.3,2]. This is useful for preventing a calling function like` NMinimize` from treating `f[x,p,n]` as symnolic, attempting preprocessing to find say a gradient, that sort of thing.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Sorry for asking too much questions. I want to maximize $f$ respect to $z$. But when I do `maxp[x_Real, y_Real, w_] = 
 First[NMaximize[{f[x, y, w], 0 <= w <= 1}, w, 
   Method -> DifferentialEvolution]]` then appears : "NMaximize::nnum: The function value -1. is not a number at {w} = {0.04573179628771076`}." How can I fix it?

Comment: The function you are maximizing is not f[x,y,z]. It is min(f[x,y,z] over (x,y)). So you need an inner optimization that minimizes f over (x,y). Use that for your outer max over z.

Comment: Also I notice you define z as a complex exponential. Is this what you really want? It won't give real values.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I edited question and added more details. $z$ should be equal to $e^{j\omega}$ .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is along the right lines, I think. But I had to change the minimization to use a log, in order for the scaling not to be too much of a problem for `FindMinimum`. I also removed the complex exponential definition of `z`. You might want to exponentiate the result. I also used an `Abs` to make the logarithm real valued, so that too could have consequences.

```
t = 0.01;
f[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Log[Abs[(((x + (t/2) y) z + ((t/2) y - x)) (1 - 
        Exp[-0.3 t]))/((z^100) (z - Exp[-0.3 t]) (z - 
         1) + ((x + (t/2) y) z + ((t/2) y - x)) (1 - Exp[-0.3 t]))]]

fzmin[z_?NumberQ] := Module[{x, y, res},
  res = FindMinimum[f[x, y, z], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
  If[! ListQ[res], -1000000., res[[1]]]]

max = 
 NMaximize[{fzmin[z], 0 <= z <= 10}, {z, 0, 10}, 
  Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

(* Out[317]= {-1.11022302463*10^-16, {z -> 0.416231991971}} *)

--- edit ---

Based on updates to the question, the code below should be appropriate. I remark that it is not hugely modified from the prior attempt.

```
T = 0.01;
f[x_, y_, w_] := (((x + (T/2) y) Exp[I w] + ((T/2) y - x)) (1 - 
       Exp[-0.3 T]))/((Exp[I w]^100) (Exp[I w] - 
        Exp[-0.3 T]) (Exp[I w] - 1) + 
        ((x + (T/2) y) Exp[I w] + ((T/2) y - x)) (1 - Exp[-0.3 T]));

g[x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ] := 
 NMaximize[{Evaluate[Abs[f[x, y, w]]], 0 <= w <= 10}, {w, 0, 10}][[1]]

NMinimize[g[x, y], {x, y}]

{0.777743387928, {x -> -6.56647441199, y -> -2.87876723563}}
```

--- end edit ---

Comment: But i doubt on the way you propose. why you first minimize $f$  then maximized the result? This is not compatible with question. I added more details to question.  $z$ should be equal to $e^{j\omega}$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I run the above code but process time is too long!
One question: Why you use `[[1]]` in code? How does it help?

Comment: (1) I would not expect a bilevel optimization to be fast. But you might be able to improve the speed by using `FindMaximum` and `FindMinimum` in place of `NMaximize` and `NMinimize`. (2) It extracts the first component of what `NMaximize` returns. That's what you want. The max value. Not the replacement rules that give the arg max. (3) You'll need to learn a bit more about Mathematica in order to use it effectively. I'd recommend experimenting some. For example, you could remove that [[1]] and run e.g. `g[1.2,3.3]` to see what it then does differently.

Comment: Thanks for everything. I hope to work more with mathematica and ask better questions in the future.