# How to implement something like NMaximize[ NMinimize [ f(x,y) , {x} ], {y} ]?

Tags: numerics

Title says it all, really.

I want to find some set of values for which a function of those values can't be made larger than a certain number, when some other values (on which that function is also dependent) are unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guard against premature evaluation of the inside minimization by putting it inside a function which won't evaluate until a numeric argument is supplied:

```
f[x_, y_] = 1 + x^2 - y^2;
fminx[y_?NumericQ] := NMinValue[f[x, y], {x}];
FindMaximum[fminx[y], {y, 1.}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {0.515133, {1., {y -> -7.45058*10^-9}}}
*)

NMaximize[fminx[y], {y}] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  {47.629574, {1., {y -> -5.83182*10^-9}}}
*)
```

`NMaximize` takes a lot longer.  You might want to tune constraints and methods to suit your objective function.

---

Comment: @quantum_loser You're welcome.  Depending on the function, one might use both local optimization functions `FindMinimum` and `FindMaximum`, which would be fastest. (But local optimization only works reliably if there is only one extremum.)

Comment: Related to [this MSE thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/l-infty-norm-minimization) on bilevel optimization.