# Minimax optimization in Mathematica

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Mathematica has functions for constrained nonlinear maximization or minimization of functions, via `FindMinimum` and `FindMaximum` or similar functions.

I need to solve minimax problems of the form:

$$\min_x \max_y f(x,y)$$

subject to equality and inequality constrains of the form:

$$g_i(x) \le 0, \quad i = 1,\dots, p$$
$$h_j(y) \ge 0, \quad j = 1,\dots, q$$

$$A x + B y = c$$

Here $f(x,y)$ is convex in $x$ (for fixed $y$) and concave in $y$ (for fixed $x$). Moreover, $g_i(x)$ are convex, $h_j(y)$ concave, and $A,B$ matrices of appropriate dimensions.

Are there numerical algorithms in mathematica for these kinds of problems?

For example, Matlab offers the function `fminimax`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the parameter range for `y` in Matlab's `fminimax` has to be finite. So this min-max-problem can be formulated as a convention optimization problem. Things become significantly harder if `y` varies over a continuous range.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I did not notice that. In my application $x,y$ are continuous, but restricted to bounded domains (in fact, convex domains).

Comment: Does the function `f` happen to be concave in `y`? In that case you can use the KKT conditions (in `y`) as constraints for the optimization problem in `x`. Otherwise, this might be a very, very hard optimization problem.

Comment: A heuristical method that might also work is fixing a start value for `x`, maximixing `f[x,y]` in `y`, taking this `y`, maximizing `f[x,y]` in x, taking this `x`, maximizing `f[x,y]` in `y`, ... until neither `x` nor `y` change (up to some tolerance of course).

Comment: Please post a concrete example.

Comment: There is [this MathGroup thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Aug/msg00370.html). Also [this MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40941/l-infty-norm-minimization).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I modified the question to add more details. But I want to maintain a general formulation, if possible.

Comment: If you post an actual cut-and-pastable example you are more likely to get takers in terms of responses with code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the Matlab documentation:

> fminimax minimizes the worst-case (largest) value of a set of
>   multivariable functions, starting at an initial estimate. This is
>   generally referred to as the minimax problem.

Doing this is straightforward in Mathematica, for example:

```
FindMinimum[{t, {t >= Sin[x], t >= Cos[x]}}, {t, x}]
```

finds the value of x such that `Max[Sin[x],Cos[x]]` is minimal.

The [example from the Matlab documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminimax.html#f616500) would be:

```
f[x_] := {
  2*x[[1]]^2 + x[[2]]^2 - 48*x[[1]] - 40*x[[2]] + 304,
  -x[[1]]^2 - 3*x[[2]]^2,
  x[[1]] + 3*x[[2]] - 18,
  -x[[1]] - x[[2]],
  x[[1]] + x[[2]] - 8
  }

FindMinimum[{t, Thread[t >= f[{x, y}]]}, {t, x, y}]
```

> {1.71811*10^-7, {t -> 1.71811*10^-7, x -> 4., y -> 4.}}

which is the same solution Matlab gives. (The [algorithm section](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminimax.html#f187550) says that `fminmax` does more or less the same thing)

---

If you want to solve a continous minimax problem, and `y`is only 1 or 2 variables, you can approximate it like this:

```
ys = Subdivide[-π, π, 100];
FindMinimum[{t, Thread[t >= Sin[x]*Sin[ys]]}, {t, x}]
```

Which is still surprisingly fast (0.03sec on my PC), but it doesn't scale if the domain of y is larger

Answer (score 6):

There are also the undocumented, internal functions:

```
Optimization`FindMinimax
Optimization`FindMaximin
Optimization`NMinimax
Optimization`NMaximin
```

A typical call has the form

```
Optimization`FindMinimax[{f, cons}, vars, opts]
```

where `f` is a vector of objective functions.  The call is translated to a call of the form

```
optimizer[{z, And @@ Flatten[{cons}, 1] && And @@ Thread[r[z, f]]}, vars, opts]
```

where `optimizer` is either `FindMinimum`, `FindMaximum`, `NMinimize`, or `NMaximize`, respectively.  Essentially, then, this implements the same approach as [@Niki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/242/niki-estner).

@Niki's first example:

```
Optimization`FindMinimax[{{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {}}, {x}]
(*  {0.707107, {x -> 0.785398}}  *)
```

My example doesn't give a good result, even with a pretty good starting point.  It gives a minimum of `1344.09` with starting values of `{{x, 5}, {y, 2}}`.  The `"InteriorPoint"` method gives a better result, a minimum of `43.1525` with automatically chosen starting points and good minimum with the starting point of `{5, 2}`:

```
Optimization`FindMinimax[{{Max[{Abs[2 x^2 + y^2 - 48 x - 40 y + 304], 
     Abs[-x^2 - 3 y^2], Abs[x + 3 y - 18], Abs[-x - y], 
     Abs[x + y - 8]}]},
  {}},
 {{x, 5}, {y, 2}}, Method -> "InteriorPoint"]
(*  {37.2375, {x -> 4.92671, y -> 2.07865}}  *)
```

Using the global optimizer `NMinimize` works a bit better:

```
Optimization`NMinimax[{{Max[{Abs[2 x^2 + y^2 - 48 x - 40 y + 304], 
     Abs[-x^2 - 3 y^2], Abs[x + 3 y - 18], Abs[-x - y], 
     Abs[x + y - 8]}]},
  {}},
 {x, y}]
(*  {37.239, {x -> 4.92601, y -> 2.07954}}  *)
```

The method `"DifferentialEvolution"` is slightly faster (1.35 sec. vs. 1.6 sec):

```
Optimization`NMinimax[{{Max[{Abs[2 x^2 + y^2 - 48 x - 40 y + 304], 
     Abs[-x^2 - 3 y^2], Abs[x + 3 y - 18], Abs[-x - y], 
     Abs[x + y - 8]}]},
  {}},
 {x, y},
 Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(*  {37.239, {x -> 4.92601, y -> 2.07954}}  *)
```

Answer (score 5):

From [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#1422430628):

> ```
> (*FindMinMax[{Max[{f1,f2,..}],constraints},vars]*)
> SetAttributes[FindMinMax, HoldAll];
> FindMinMax[{f_Max, cons_}, vars_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
>   With[{res = iFindMinMax[{f, cons}, vars, opts]}, 
>    res /; ListQ[res]];
> iFindMinMax[{ff_Max, cons_}, vars_, opts___?OptionQ] := 
>   Module[{z, res, f = List @@ ff},
>       res = FindMinimum[{z, (And @@ cons) && (And @@ Thread[z >= f])}, 
>      Append[Flatten[{vars}, 1], z], opts]; 
>    If[ListQ[res], {z /. res[[2]], 
>      Thread[vars -> (vars /. res[[2]])]}]];
> ```

An example:

> ```
> FindMinMax[{Max[{Abs[2 x^2 + y^2 - 48 x - 40 y + 304], 
>     Abs[-x^2 - 3 y^2], Abs[x + 3 y - 18], Abs[-x - y], 
>     Abs[ x + y - 8]}], {}}, {x, y}]
>
> (*  {37.2356, {x -> 4.92563, y -> 2.07956}}  *)
> ```

A few more examples are in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but in my answer I tried to solve a continuous problem.  Do you have an idea, how to improve my approach, which is very slow(~5min)?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I don't understand the first part of your comment: the objective function in the example I used from the docs is continuous.  At first glance, I would guess your approach is slow because global minimization with `NMinimize` is often slow.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could split your problem:

As an example I consider the function

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[(x - Pi/4) ( y - Pi/8)] Cos[y]
```

First step looks for maxima y[x]

```
maxy[x_?NumericQ] := y /. NMaximize[ {f[x, y], 0 <= y <= 3/2 Pi}, y][[2]]
```

Among all these points `{x,maxy[x],f[x,maxy[x]]}` the minimum is evaluated:

```
min = NMinimize[{f[x, maxy[x]] , 0 <= x <= Pi}, x ]
(* takes some time...*)
```

and plotted (red point is the minmax!)

```
minP = {x /. #[[2]], maxy[x /. #[[2]]], #[[1]]} &[min];
(*{0.785398, 3.45703, 9.78576*10^-11}*)
Show[{Plot3D[ f[x, y], {x, 0, Pi}, {y, 0,  3/2 Pi}, Mesh -> False,AxesLabel -> {x, y, f}],Graphics3D [{Gray, 
Point[Table[{x, maxy[x], f[x, maxy[x]]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/100}]], 
Red, PointSize[.025], Point[minP]}] }, AxesLabel -> {x, y, "f[x,y]"}]
```

[image]