# Evaluation of parameter inside FindMaximum

Tags: variable-definitions

Why does this work:

```
Table[ FindMaximum[x^2 - y^2, {y, 1}][[1]], {x, 1}]
```

While this does not:

```
FindMinimum[ FindMaximum[x^2 - y^2, {y, 1}][[1]], {x, 1}]
```

How can I make it work?  It is not substituting the value of x before maximizing, but nothing I try seems to help.

Answer (score 1):

The inner `FindMaximum` gives a result, which doesn't depend on x!

Try

```
max = MaxValue[{x^2 - y^2 }, y] (* x^2, which implies y==0 *)
minmax = FindMinimum[ max, x] (* {0., {x -> 0.}}*)
```

which gives the sollution `x==0, y==0` for your minmax-problem

```
Show[{Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}],
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[.05],Point[{x, y, x^2 - y^2} /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}]}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I watered down the original problem, which didn't have this nice symmetry, and is too complicated for an analytic solution.  Both the maximum and minimum need to be determined numerically, one as a function of the other.  Is there any way to accommodate that?

Comment: In this link "https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171531/minimax-optimization-in-mathematica/171562#171562"  Michael E2 shows how to realize minmax problems in MMA