# Given a function $f(t,s)$, compute $\max_{t_2\in [0,1]}\min_{t_1\in [0,1]} |f(t_1,s_1)-f(t_2,s_2)|$

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, algorithm, maximum

Given a continuous and bounded function $f(t,s)$, $t,s\in[0,1]$, I would like to compute 
$$\max_{t_2\in [0,1]}\min_{t_1\in [0,1]} |f(t_1,s_1)-f(t_2,s_2)|,$$
for each numeric values of $s_1$ and $s_2$. I tried by combining NMaxValue and NMinValue but the time is prohibitively large.

I read on the Internet that this distance is sometimes referred to as Fréchet or Hausdorff distance. Is there a built-in function in Mathematica that solves this max-min problem (something like NMaxMinValue)? Or which would be the correct algorithm to proceed with?

Comment: Is the domain of the variable in the question the same as the real problem you want to solve?

Comment: @Xminer Yes. I have a particular function on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. I tried to apply NMaxValue of NMinValue. Although after a long time I obtain the correct max-min value, I would like a faster procedure than just combining these two functions. I would expect something as NMaxMinValue. As this distance has a well-known name (Fréchet or Hausdorff), maybe it has been already implemented in Mathematica.

Comment: I  searched this community and documents,but no builtin-function for Hausdorff distance here. so,we have to build new one.

Comment: Some undocumented minmax routines exists [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/171531/minimax-optimization-in-mathematica/172108#172108)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Oh, I've re-invented the degraded wheels...

Comment: @ Xminer No, no , a very interesting approach!

Comment: Might do a web search on "bilevel optimization stack exchange mathematica" (but without the quotes)

Answer (score 1):

(*This is example*)
There is No <s>Built-in</s>,*Documented* Function for [Hausdorff distance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) 
Anyway,my code is the following:

```
f[t_, s_] := Cos[t]*Cos[s];
domain = Range[0, 1, 0.01];
Do[
  Do[
    funvalue[i, j] = f[i, j];
    ,
    {i, domain}];
  , {j, domain}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 data = Outer[
   With[{s1 = #1, s2 = #2},
     Max[
      MapThread[
       With[{x = #},
         Min[
          MapThread[
           (Abs[funvalue[x, s1] - funvalue[#, s2]]) &
           , {domain}]
          ]
         ] &,
       {domain}]
      ]
     ] &,
   domain, domain];

 ArrayPlot[data]]
```

[image]