# What is the most reliable way to find a particular function?

Tags: undocumented, internals

I learned there're built-in functions which is not documented　[from this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199764/given-a-function-ft-s-compute-max-t-2-in-0-1-min-t-1-in-0-1-ft/199775#199775).

After this ,
 I tried looking for something which is usable for me,
then noticed that with `? something*`, 
I can't find the packages like `Optimization` without specifying  `?Optimization'*`.

Is there any way to search all-builtin functions with arbitrary phrase?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Names["*`*" <> pattern <> "*"]
```

or

```
?*`*pattern*
```

should find symbols containing `pattern`.