# Optimization problem with parameter dependent interval of functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am working on an optimization problem but ran into a problem.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
foo1a[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
foo1b[t_] := {Cos[t], -Sin[t]}
foo1[a_] := 
 NMaxValue[{t + EuclideanDistance[foo1a[t], foo1b[t]] - a, 
   a <= t <= 2 a}, t]

foo2a[t_] := {-Cos[t], Sin[t]}
foo2b[t_] := {-Cos[t], -Sin[t]}
foo2[a_] := 
 NMaxValue[{t + EuclideanDistance[foo2a[t], foo2b[t]]*(0.5 + a), 
   a <= t <= 2 a}, t]

NMinimize[Max[foo1[a], foo2[a]], a]
```

So I want to minimize the max value of several functions, which return the max value of a function over a given interval. The problem is that the interval depends on the parameters but mathematica wants me to have fixed parameters (Returns error: *NMaxValue: The following constraints are not valid: {a<=t,t<=2 a}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables.*).

Is there any way to solve this or could another approach circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to solve a minimax problem, i.e. finding the value of  your parameter $a$ that minimizes a function defined as the maximum of other functions. Take a look at [a tutorial on these problems](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLocalNumerical.html#1422430628) and at previous questions on this site, among which [Minimax optimization in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/171531/27951) provides multiple approaches.

First, you should restrict evaluation of the `NMaxValue` functions so they only evaluate after $a$ is given a numerical value. To achieve that, use `NumericQ` in the definition of the corresponding functions (see [this FAQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/27951)):

```
ClearAll[foo1a, foo1b, foo1]
foo1a[t_] := {Cos[t], Sin[t]}
foo1b[t_] := {Cos[t], -Sin[t]}
foo1[a_?NumericQ] := 
  NMaxValue[{t + EuclideanDistance[foo1a[t], foo1b[t]] - a, a <= t <= 2 a}, t]

ClearAll[foo2a, foo2b, foo2]
foo2a[t_] := {-Cos[t], Sin[t]}
foo2b[t_] := {-Cos[t], -Sin[t]}
foo2[a_?NumericQ] := 
  NMaxValue[{t + EuclideanDistance[foo2a[t], foo2b[t]]*(0.5 + a), a <= t <= 2 a}, t]
```

Even after this, however, you get warnings when trying to run `NMinimize` with the modified definitions:

> NMaxValue::nsol There are no points that satisfy the constraints {False}.

This is a problem with your constraints in the `NMaxValue` calls. In fact, the constraint $a\leq t\leq 2a$ is automatically false for any value of $t$ when $a$ is negative. This implies to me that your formulation **implicitly  assumes that $a$ is non-negative** (or you have to rethink your constraints). That's fine, but we should make the minimizer aware of that constraint!

Including that constraint, and switching to the [undocumented internal minimax solver](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172108/27951) for speed:

```
Optimization`FindMinimax[{{Max[foo1[a], foo2[a]]}, {a >= 0}}, {a}]

(* Out: {1.21818*10^-7, {a -> 8.18183*10^-9}} *)
```

This essentially says that the minimum value is $0$, and it is attained for $a=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the in-depth answer and all the pointers! Adding NumericQ did the trick. Yeah, my posted sample problem might not make sense, but I could apply everything to my more complex problem.

Answer (score 1):

In version 13 on Windows 10

```
NMinimize[{Max[Evaluate[foo1[a]], Evaluate[foo2[a]]], a >= 0}, a, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
```

> `{1.14277*10^-8, {a -> 2.28555*10^-9}}`

in few minutes.

Comment: This gets it running, thanks. It didn't return the optimal solution for my more complex problem(but it might with some tweaking), so I will keep this approach in mind if I run into problems with MarcoB's approach.

Comment: @Wurzel: What was asked that was answered. You wrote " It didn't return the optimal solution for my more complex problem". Ask it as a new question. Good luck and deep regard!